# Error while integrating google test into existing CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a working project and I want to add google test into it, but one difference is, my `main()` function is in a different file.

This is my project structure:

```
-test
    - include
        - file.h
        - file1.h
        - file2.h
    - file.cpp
    - file1.cpp
    - file2.cpp
    - main.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - unitTest
        -CMakeLists.txt
        -test_main.cpp
```

My *main* `CMakeLists.txt` file links a lot of libs and files that the `test_main.cpp` will also need, but it also creates an executable file. I tried using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655117/adding-googletest-to-existing-cmake-project) but I can't figure out how to make it work or even if it's possible.

This is my `unitTest/CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
project(Google_tests)
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
        EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
    include_directories("${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
endif()

# Now simply link against gtest or gtest_main as needed. Eg

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CMakeLists.txt)
add_executable(Google_tests test_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Google_tests gtest gtest_main)
add_test(NAME example_test COMMAND Google_tests)
```

This CMakeList file is from [google test git hub](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project), and I also tried to do what the Clion Manual [wrote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-google-test-run-debug-configuration-for-test.html#add-google-tests),
but it's still not working. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
-- Configuring done 
CMake Error at /home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/test/CMakeLists.txt:74 (add_executable):   
  Cannot find source file:

    main.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm   .hpp .hxx .in .txx 
Call Stack (most recent call first):   
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (include)

CMake Error at /home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/test/CMakeLists.txt:74 (add_executable):   
  No SOURCES given to target: test 
Call Stack (most recent call first):   
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (include)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Here is the test/CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    add_definitions(-DRELEASE=1)
    add_definitions(-DDEBUG=0)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2")
else()
    add_definitions(-DRELEASE=0)
    add_definitions(-DDEBUG=1)
endif ()

include_directories(/include)


link_directories(list of dir)

#link_libraries(../lib/external/tinyxml2-master)
find_package(Threads) # for enableing std::thread
find_library(conn_LIB connlib)

SET(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
      file.cpp file.h
      file1.cpp file1.h
      file2.cpp file2.h )
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

SET(LBS list of libs)

target_link_libraries(test ${list of libs} pq)
```

Comment: You haven't shown all the code. The error occurs here `test/CMakeLists.txt`, but you haven't mentioned this CMake file in your project hierarchy, nor have you shown the CMake code where you add `main.cpp` to a target. There is not enough info here to understand what is going on, so please create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue. Also, this line looks very odd `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CMakeLists.txt)` and should probably be avoided.

Comment: @squareskittles edit `root` to `test`, also the line `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CMakeLists.txt)` is for to link all the libs and project file - is there a way to do it without copy all `test/CMakeList.txt` into the `test/unitTest/CMakeList.txt?

Comment: Typically, CMake is run by issuing the `cmake` command on the **top-level** CMake file in the project hierarchy. If you do this, you can use the command `add_subdirectory()` in the top-level CMake file to traverse to the CMake file in the `unitTest` subdirectory. Traversing *backwards* up thru parent directories, as in your example, is not recommended. Regardless, the CMake code where `main.cpp` is added is still not shown.

Comment: @squareskittles added the `test/CMakeList.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line in your `unitTest/CMakeLists.txt` file is leading to behavior you may not expect:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CMakeLists.txt)
```

From the documentation for [`include`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/include.html), this command will:

> Load and run CMake code from a file or module.

This command is typically reserved for loading CMake [Find Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) or other *custom* CMake modules (i.e. `*.cmake` files). As such, this **does not** change the current CMake source directory, so files mentioned in `test/CMakeLists.txt` are still interpreted *with respect to* the child directory `test/unitTest`. After calling `include()`, CMake looks in `test/unitTest` for the `main.cpp` file (and others) but it does not exist there. Hence, CMake prints the error.

Although not recommended, if you **really** need to traverse to the parent CMakeLists.txt file (using `include()`) like this, you can use [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) to refer to the source files:

```
SET(SOURCE_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/file.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file1.cpp 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/file1.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file2.cpp 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/file2.h 
)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

You likely need to make similar changes to other *relative* references in the `test/CMakeLists.txt` file, to prevent errors resulting from this abnormal approach.

---

My recommendation is to instead run CMake from your **top-level** CMakeLists.txt file, and simply use the following line to traverse to the CMake file in the sub-directory:

```
add_subdirectory(unitTest)
```